# how to call same function with different parameter and put it in one list

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a service call for each page and trying to put in a list. Here is my code.

```
loadItems:function(id,pageNo){
    itemsList =[];
    var items =[];
     for (var i = 1; i <=pageNo; i++){
                this.getPages(id,i).then(function(response){
                   items[i] =response.items;                    
                },function(response){
                   // error
                });
    }

    //here Iam trying to put all items in itemsList. here item[1] store all items from page1 say 10 items then item[2] from page2. itemlist is the final list contains all items
    return messageList;    
},
getPages:function(id,pageNo){
 data.payload = {
                id: id,
                page: pageNo,               
            };
            var promise = $http.post( url,data); 
            return promise;
        },
}
```

How can I keep all this in one list.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `promise` which will `resolve` (or `reject`) once all the pages are processed. once the promise is resolved concatenate results of `items` array into `itemsList`

You may use a watcher on `items` array to see when it becomes full and resolve the outer promise. (Then there may be more elegant ways of doing the *watching*).

Hope this helps

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is my 2 cents solution to the problem with coding. Apparently the item list only get called right after the http post finish loading the page.

You can make your own dummy welcome.html without html code ie.

```html
Hello AngularJS Students
```

Hope this helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

<script>

var url = "welcome.html";

var data = {
    id: 1,
    page: 1               
};

var items = [];
var pageNo = 3;
var flag = true;

function getItems(){
 //alert(items[0]);
 for (var i = 1; i <=pageNo && items[i]!=null; i++){
  alert("Get item: " + i+ " " + items[i]);
 }
 return items;
}

function setItems(response){

//inserted into a list
 for (j = 1; j <=pageNo; j++){
    
  if(items[j]==null){
   items[j]=response.data;
   alert(j+" "+items[j]);
   break;
  }
 }

}

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  
  for (i = 1; i <=pageNo; i++){
  data = {     
     id: data.id,
     page: i           
      };
   
  $http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
   $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
   setItems(response);
   
   //Items exist within the http post call.
   getItems();
   
  });
  //
  }
  
  
  
});





</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the derived promises and use `$q.all`

```
loadItems:function(id,pageNo){
    itemsList =[];
    var items = [];
    var promises = [];
    var self = this;
    for (var i = 1; i <=pageNo; i++){
         //IIFE closure
         (function (i) {
              var derivedPromise =
                  self.getPages(id,i).then(function(response){
                      items[i] = response.data;
                      return response.data;                
                  },function(errorResponse){
                      //error
                      throw errorResponse;
                  });
              promises.push(derivedPromise);
         })(i);
    }
    return $q.all(promises);    
},
```

The `$q.all` promise will either be fulfulled with an array of items or be rejected with the first error response.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I used this code and getting "this.getPages not defined". do I have to use any scope?

Comment: it is not working,derviedpromise is not holding the list and promises does not have any value. how to hold all promises?

Comment: See my update. I added binding: `var self = this;` and used `self.getPages(...` .

Comment: Thanks for the update. I verfied values in derviedPromise and promises. they are not holding values.items[i] holding list but not promises.could you give update on this please.